# Accesing windows server 64 bits Registry info using citrix

Tags: windows-server-2008, powerbuilder, citrix

trying to save file using Powerbuilder Datawindow Save As function 
for path we are using

RegistryGet(  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\shell folders",   "Desktop", RegString!, ls_ret)

but when we login through citrix.

Not able to get this path.

When looged in as administrator getting  this path but for other users we are not getting the path .
We also given full permission to particularly this registry but still not getting.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be Citrix specific, to simplify, add a user to Remote Desktop group and login directly via RDP (without Citrix), you should get the same behavior